# How to get current branch name in TortoiseGit?

Tags: tortoise-git

What is the quickest way to copy current branch name to clipboard?

What I usually do is this:

1. Open the log.
2. Click branch name in the left upper corner of the window
3. Then F2 to edit this name
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Way 1:

1. Right click in repo, and click `Push`
2. Copy that `Local` text

Way 2: (TortoiseGit 2.5.0)

1. Open log dialog
2. Right click on the branch name label
3. Click "Copy to clipboard -> Tag/branch names"

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on any file or folder in an explorer window
2. Select properties
3. Select the Git tab
4. The current branch name is already selected and can be copied immediately

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already got well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.

Comment: @Toto Thank you! I found this question and answer using a search engine and thought the way I posted was even better. I didn't want to keep it to myself in case any others searching the web found it as well. Thus I thought it was substantial enough, sorry if it was not, but I guess it might be a bit subjective as well.